# How do I modify which text and image that show on Facebook sharing using their SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Trying to traverse Facebook's docs is like traversing a busy highway blindfolded. I have initialized their Javascript SDK like this:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '597118477106840',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.5'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I have a share button of my own design:

```
<button class="ui facebook button">Share</button>
```

**And then we come to what to actually do when it's clicked.**

Facebook gives very confusing examples. **Their first:**

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

And, just below this snippet, they say:

> Include open graph meta tags on the page at this URL to customize the
>   story that is shared back to Facebook.

All right, simple enough. So I do that:

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="my-page.com" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="I really hate Facebook's docs" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="Sub text?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="image.jpg" />
```

However, this doesn't work at all. It uses the same automatically generated image and text for the sharing. So I read on and find this quote:

> Trigger a Share Dialog using the FB.ui function with the
>   share_open_graph method parameter to share an Open Graph story.

Okay, you literally just said that I could do it with the regular method, but let's try this then. Their snippet:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share_open_graph',
  action_type: 'og.likes',
  action_properties: JSON.stringify({
      object:'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  })
}, function(response){});
```

This, when changing the `object` to my webpage url, turns up a different error every time. Sometimes it says `og:title` isn't a string. Sometimes it tries to like the page (but no like shows up when going through with it). Sometimes it tries to share, again with the wrong image and text. It runs through a couple of other errors as well.

What even is `og.likes`? Facebook refuses to list any other `action_types` as well as `action_properties` and fails to explain what they are. They write this:

> A string specifying which Open Graph action type to publish, e.g.,
>   og.likes for the built in like type.

It should be noted that this example is taken from how to **SHARE** stuff, not like them. So what gives?

**How do I do this the right way?**

Comment: Using OG meta tags is the easiest way. But if Facebook has read your page already before you inserted those tags, you need to re-scrape it, so that Facebook updates its cache. Use the debug tool to re-scrape your URL – it will also tell you if your OG meta data is correct. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: @CBroe Do I need to use `share_open_graph` to use the meta tags? The docs claim that I do and that I don't...

Comment: And `og.likes` is an Open Graph action, that allows you to let people like external sites via API.

Comment: No, you don’t need to use `share_open_graph` (and neither do the docs “claim” you had to.)

Comment: Oh, okay. But yeah they do: "Trigger a Share Dialog using the FB.ui function with the share_open_graph method parameter to share an Open Graph story."

Comment: Yes, “to share an Open Graph story” – that is the important part here. If you just want to post a simple link, and not an Open Graph story (which would consist of an action the user undertakes, and an object which he undertakes it upon), then that is a totally different thing.

Comment: @CBroe Okay, guess the confusion arrives from their using the same term for two different things then. First, `Open Graph story` was your own text/image in the share page. Then it is something else. I still don't understand. But I have learned from the debugger that their own snippet of tags didn't include some important parts, so thanks for that link.

Comment: _“First, Open Graph story was your own text/image in the share page”_ – where does it say that?

Comment: @CBroe "Include open graph meta tags on the page at this URL to customize the story that is shared back to Facebook."

Comment: Well, they consider posting a link a “story” as well (it will show up on timeline titled “Foo shared a link” or something like that) – but that is not an Open Graph Story.

Comment: @CBroe Lol okay. As I said, brilliantly named! I think I got it to work now, so thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CBroe in the comments, I found [the debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), which was very helpful as it not only debugs but rescrapes the page to get the right information (of course, the docs couldn't link to that because then they wouldn't actually be useless).

"Open Graph" denotes two different things, which is just brilliant. So, no, there is no need to post an "Open Graph story" to use the tags. If you use `open_graph_story` the debugger will throw all kinds of weird errors, but going back to the regular `share` it works except for this:

`<meta property="og:image"              content="image.jpg" />`

This needs to be an absolute url, because it's infinitely stupid like that.

Fixing that, everything works as it should.

Comment: The docs do mention the debug tool, here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#debug